# How to make the static content hosted in CDN accessible via URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cdn

So far I have written the following shell script to execute commands using Gcloud CLI. Can you please review and suggest what needs to be added, remomved or modified to make the files in CDN accessible?

I am also interested in getting domain name of the CDN endpoint instead of the IP address that I have managed get so far. I want to set it as PUBLIC_URL to my react app's build step. Can you please suggest corresponding GCLOUD CLI commands to get access to that domain/host name of Cloud CDN endpoint created by this script?

```
REGION="europe-west3"
gcloud config set run/region "$REGION"

#!/bin/bash

# Set the variables
export CONTENT="static-content"
export BUCKET_NAME="$CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME-$CONTENT"
export CDN_NAME="$CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME-$CONTENT-cdn"

# Check if the bucket exists
if gsutil ls -p "$PROJECT_ID" -b "gs://$BUCKET_NAME" 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "Bucket '$BUCKET_NAME' already exists."
else
  echo "Creating bucket '$BUCKET_NAME'..."
  gsutil mb -p "$PROJECT_ID" -c standard -l $REGION -b on "gs://$BUCKET_NAME"
fi

# Check if the CDN exists
if gcloud compute backend-buckets describe "$CDN_NAME" --project "$PROJECT_ID" 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "CDN '$CDN_NAME' already exists."
else
  echo "Creating CDN '$CDN_NAME'..."
  gcloud compute backend-buckets create "$CDN_NAME" --gcs-bucket-name "$BUCKET_NAME" --project "$PROJECT_ID"
fi

# Enable the CDN for the backend bucket
gcloud compute backend-buckets update "$CDN_NAME" --project "$PROJECT_ID" --enable-cdn

if ! gcloud compute url-maps describe "$CDN_NAME" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # Create the URL map
    gcloud compute url-maps create "$CDN_NAME" --default-backend-bucket="$CDN_NAME"
else
  echo "URL map $CDN_NAME already exists. Reusing."
fi

# Invalidate cache if CDN exists
if gcloud compute url-maps describe "$CDN_NAME" --project "$PROJECT_ID" 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "Invalidating cache for CDN '$CDN_NAME'..."
  gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache "$CDN_NAME" --project "$PROJECT_ID" --path "/*" &
fi
# Check if CDN already exists
if ! gcloud compute target-http-proxies describe $CDN_NAME --project=$PROJECT_ID &> /dev/null; then
  # Create a new target HTTP proxy
  gcloud compute target-http-proxies create $CDN_NAME \
    --url-map $CDN_NAME \
    --project $PROJECT_ID
fi

# Check if global forwarding rule already exists
if ! gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe $CDN_NAME --global --project=$PROJECT_ID &> /dev/null; then
  # Create a new global forwarding rule
  gcloud compute forwarding-rules create $CDN_NAME \
    --global \
    --target-http-proxy $CDN_NAME \
    --ports 80 \
    --project $PROJECT_ID
fi

# Get the CDN endpoint URL
CDN_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe $CDN_NAME \
  --global \
  --format='get(IPAddress)' \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID)

#CDN_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud compute backend-buckets describe "$CDN_NAME" --project "$PROJECT_ID" --format="value(cdnPolicy.cacheKeyPolicy.includeHost)")

# Set the PUBLIC_URL environment variable
export PUBLIC_URL="https://$CDN_ENDPOINT"
echo "PUBLIC_URL: $PUBLIC_URL"
yarn build:custom
# Sync build folder with bucket in cloud storage
gsutil -m rsync -R ./build/ "gs://$BUCKET_NAME"
```